# Checking for an SQL result in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I need to check if my SQL statement returned any results from the Access db I'm using to store my data.

I have this code atm:

```
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Computing Project\database.mdb;")
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM(" & roomvar.ToLower() & ") WHERE (((" & roomvar.ToLower() & ".date)=" & Chr(34) & dtpDate.Value.Date & Chr(34) & "))", cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While dr.Read()

            End While
        End If
        dr.Close()
```

I would like to be able to check (maybe via a boolean value or something) that this result returned a query. I'm using VB.net.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Use the [OleDbDataReader.HasRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.hasrows.aspx) Property after your call to ExecuteReader.

```
    cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Computing Project\database.mdb;")
    cn.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM(" & roomvar.ToLower() & ") WHERE (((" & roomvar.ToLower() & ".date)=" & Chr(34) & dtpDate.Value.Date & Chr(34) & "))", cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    hasRows = dr.HasRows

    dr.Close()
```

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that addressed the issue without moving through the data.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer, I guess, is this:

```
    Dim hasResults as Boolean = false
    cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Computing Project\database.mdb;")
    cn.Open()
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM(" & roomvar.ToLower() & ") WHERE (((" & roomvar.ToLower() & ".date)=" & Chr(34) & dtpDate.Value.Date & Chr(34) & "))", cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
             hasResults = true
        End While
    End If
    dr.Close()
```

My vb-syntax is a little rusty, but you get the idea.
But I'm not sure that this is what you actually want.

Another variant could be

```
Dim hasResults as Boolean = false
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Computing Project\database.mdb;")
cn.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT 1 FROM(" & roomvar.ToLower() & ") WHERE (((" & roomvar.ToLower() & ".date)=" & Chr(34) & dtpDate.Value.Date & Chr(34) & "))", cn)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read() Then
         hasResults = true
    End If
End If
dr.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Computing Project\database.mdb;")
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM({0}) WHERE ((({0}.date)=""{1}""))", roomvar.ToLower(), dtpDate.Value.Date), cn)
        Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            hasResults = dr.Read()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

I strongly suggest you look at passing the `dtpDate` value as a parameter instead of a literal value in the command text, e.g.:

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Computing Project\database.mdb;")
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM({0}) WHERE ((({0}.date)=?))", roomvar.ToLower()), cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtpDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtpDate.Value.Date
        Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            hasResults = dr.Read()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Passing the date as a parameter will help avoid internationalisation issues (i.e. works on non-US locales). And it's just generally more robust.